# How to iterate over this array structure

Tags: javascript

I can parse this by hand. I am interested in the idiomatic way of doing it in JavaScript.

What confuses me is that all the examples I see have a key/value names for the columns. And, the fields are separated by `{}`, not `[]`:

```
[
  ["MMM",0.0371],
  ["ADBE",0.0413]
]
```

Comment: I'd suggest cracking open your intro to JS book again and reviewing the part about basic data structures, especially arrays vs. objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse by hand"?

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 you can write:

```
for (const [key, value] of JSON.parse(str)) {

}
```

This uses [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) with a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop. If you need compatibility with older versions of JavaScript, transpile your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: @Jonasw The original question said it was JSON, which is a string.

Answer (score 1):

If fact. This example is an Array of arrays in `Javascript`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Access an array value of a JSON object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var myObj, x;
myObj = [
  ["MMM",0.0371],
  ["ADBE",0.0413]
]
;
x = myObj[0][0];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the forEach method

```js
var arr = [
  ["MMM",0.0371],
  ["ADBE",0.0413]
]

arr.forEach(function(v1){
  v1.forEach(function(v2){
    console.log(v2)
  })
})
```

Comment: Note: `.forEach` is not an "iterator". [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators) is an iterator.

Comment: Right. Changed the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignment to iterate each array as key, value pairs. If data is actually `JSON` and not a JavaScript object call `JSON.parse()` on `JSON` first

```js
[
  ["MMM", 0.0371],
  ["ADBE", 0.0413]
]
.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value)
})
```

```js
JSON.parse('[["MMM", 0.0371],["ADBE", 0.0413]]')
.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value)
})
```

Comment: This may be a little over the head of the OP, who seems not to clearly understand the difference between arrays and objects.

Comment: @torazaburo Possibly. OP now has ability to learn from provided answers. Wanted to clarify that the syntax `[key, value]` in relation to an apparent single element of an array (or object) is termed destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In <ES6 you can write:

```
var arr = /* your array */;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var key   = arr[i][0],
        value = arr[i][1];

    // do things with `key` and `value`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES5 which is probably your best bet with browser inconsistencies you could either use a for loop or a foreach.  Also map, filter, reduce depending on what you want to do.

Fiddle

```js
var arr = [
  ["MMM",0.0371],
  ["ADBE",0.0413]
]


arr.forEach(function (el) {
  console.log(el[0])
  console.log(el[1])
})


// This will convert it to key value pairs
var keyvaluearr = arr.map(function (el) {
  return {
    name: el[0],
    value: el[1]
  }
})

console.log(keyvaluearr)

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var el = arr[i]
  console.log(el[0])
  console.log(el[1])
}
```